# Why does SciPy's curve_fit function care about the type of xdata?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I was trying to fit some data using SciPy's `curve_fit` and got really weird results. So I tried and tried and tested and found the issue in the type of `xdata`. When `xdata` is of type `int`, the results become very weird. But that does not hold for all functions `f`. I tested with polynoms up to order 6. From order 3 and above, results became weird.

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def poly4(x, a, b, c, d, e):
    return a*np.power(x,4) + b*np.power(x,3) + c*np.power(x,2) + d*x + e

x = np.linspace(0, 9.6, 2400)
y = poly4(x, 0.03, -0.68, 5.6, -22, 1351)

x1 = np.arange(0, 2400, 1, dtype=np.dtype('float'))
x2 = np.arange(0, 2400, 1, dtype=np.dtype('int'))

popt1,_ = curve_fit(poly4, x1, y)
popt2,_ = curve_fit(poly4, x2, y)

f1 = poly4(x1, *popt1)
f2 = poly4(x2, *popt2)
```

Plotting these values with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(f1, label='f1, float range')
plt.plot(f2, label='f2, int range')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

gives

[image: curve_fit plot with int and float range]

The blue line is exactly what the result should look like. Looking at the `curve_fit` output with

```
print(popt1)
print(popt2)
```

gives

> [  9.05733149e-12  -4.92513534e-08   9.73032914e-05  -9.17048770e-02
>      1.35100000e+03]
>
> [  3.52993170e-11  -1.52725549e-10   9.38577666e-06  -3.58806105e-02
>      1.34272489e+03]

Why are these results so different? Well, obviously, because of the data type of `xdata`. But why should `curve_fit` care about the data type of `xdata`? I do not see the reasoning behind that and did not find any documentation about it.

Edit: Tested on `python 3.6.3` with `scipy 0.19.1` and `python 3.7.1` with `scipy 1.1.0`. Both on Windows.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the version. On python `3.6.5`, both `int` and `float` types gives the same result (which you expect). The scipy version I'm using is `1.1.0`

Comment: @Bazingaa thats weird. See my edit.

Comment: My numpy version is `'1.14.3'`. I copy pasted your code again and got the desired overlapping curves for both

Comment: Same result on my system, but got same results for `x1` and `x2` by replacing `power` with `float_power`

Comment: I also tried matplotlib `3.0.0`, numpy `1.15.2` and python `3.5.5` and still getting same overlapping curves. I am **literally** copy pasting your code on different machines

Comment: Tagged "numpy" and "matplotlib" as the exact issue remains unclear

Comment: `2400**4` results in `np.int` overflow,  that's why you see the serrated pattern for large enough `x`. In fact, for a power of 4, overflow occurs as early as `x=216`

Comment: @Brenlla thanks! that explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `curve_fit`that cares about the type of `x`, it's your function `poly4`. Numpy preserves the type of the arrays in its operations. Since you are taking the n-power of an integer, you will quickly run into an integer overflow, which therefore produces unexpected results.

See for example the output of np.power(x,3):

```
x = np.arange(0,2400,1, dtype=np.int32)
plt.plot(x,np.power(x,3))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem you and everyone who can't reproduce your problem is running into is that the size of `np.dtype('int')` is different on different platforms. If you replace your declarations of `x1` and `x2` with:

```
x1 = np.arange(0, 2400, 1, dtype=np.dtype('float'))
x2 = np.arange(0, 2400, 1, dtype=np.int32)
```

then you can consistently reproduce the strange output regardless of platform:

[image]

The original issue is caused by the fact that `np.int32` is too small to deal with some of the very large numbers that you're calculating, and the values of intermediate calculation overflow. So the result of:

```
poly4(np.arange(2000, 2010, dtype=np.int32), 0.03, -0.68, 5.6, -22, 1351)
# array([4.60917546e+08, 3.82703937e+08, 4.34772636e+08, 3.59427040e+08,
   4.14366625e+08, 3.41894792e+08, 3.99711018e+08, 3.30118704e+08,
   3.90817330e+08, 3.24110298e+08])
```

looks very different from the result of:

```
poly4(np.arange(2000, 2010, dtype=np.int64), 0.03, -0.68, 5.6, -22, 1351)
# array([4.74582357e+11, 4.75534936e+11, 4.76488948e+11, 4.77444394e+11,
   4.78401277e+11, 4.79359597e+11, 4.80319357e+11, 4.81280557e+11,
   4.82243198e+11, 4.83207283e+11])
```